# pytesseract Erase table borders as delicately as possible

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract, pytesser

I am using pytesseract and opencv to erase the borders of an image.
to extract text from image using tesseract

This is the source code I wrote based on this post.
[What's the way to remove all lines and borders in image(keep texts) programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949831/whats-the-way-to-remove-all-lines-and-borders-in-imagekeep-texts-programmatic)

```
import cv2
import os
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
     import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

image = cv2.imread("D://ocrtestimg//id.jpg")
result = image.copy() 

gray = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (30,1))
remove_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)

cnts = cv2.findContours(remove_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 5) # contours 그리기


vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,30))
remove_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(remove_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 5)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
cv2.waitKey()

image = cv2.imread('result.png')
result = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

filename = "{}.png".format(os.getpid())
print(filename)
cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)

#Simple image to string- OCR
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename), lang='eng') 
os.remove(filename)
print(text)

cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

image with borders removed
[image]

The image quality is poor, so the vertical lines in the table are broken.
What additional work do I need to do to erase this broken line?
Even if you increase the dpi by importing an image or increase the size of the photo, the broken vertical lines are not erased.

Comment: Do you **only** need the lines to be removed (why using Tesseract then?), or do you **actually** want the numbers to be read from the table (removing the lines may not be necessary)? Please clarify.

Comment: The goal is to read the text. The reason I want to remove the border is because it treats the border as text and gives weird values.

Comment: Make your vertical kernel smaller than the lines and larger than the letters. So about 13 or 14 pixels. Then try your code again. That should get rid of the vertical lines.

Comment: All I had to do was edit the vertical value. 
For example : cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,8))
thank you