# MLKIT Text recognition not getting all the numbers ( single digit ) from image

Tags: android, google-mlkit, text-recognition

I am trying to get a sudoku board from an image using MLKIT Text Recognition but not all numbers are getting recognized.

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBK1v.jpg)

I thought the lines may interfere with the detection so I removed all the lines ( using the 1st solution from [How to remove all lines and borders in an image while keeping text programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949831/how-to-remove-all-lines-and-borders-in-an-image-while-keeping-text-programmatica)) but still numbers are not recognized well.

Does MLKIT have difficulties in recognizing single digit numbers or I am doing something wrong?

This is the code that I'm using:

```
public static void recognizeTextFromImage(Mat mRGBA){

    Bitmap bitmapImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRGBA.cols(), mRGBA.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(mRGBA, bitmapImage);
    InputImage inImg = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmapImage, 0);

    Task<Text> result = textRecognizer.process(inImg)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Text>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Text text) {
                    Log.e("MLKIT", "Task success");

                    for(Text.TextBlock block: text.getTextBlocks()){
                        String blockText = block.getText();
                        for(Text.Line line: block.getLines()){
                            for(Text.Element element: line.getElements()){
                                String elText = element.getText();
                                android.graphics.Rect rect = element.getBoundingBox();

                                Log.e("MLKIT", elText);
                                Imgproc.rectangle(mRGBA, new Point(rect.left, rect.top), new Point(rect.right, rect.bottom), new Scalar(255, 0, 255 ), 1, Imgproc.LINE_AA);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e("MLKIT", "Task fail");
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-recognize-text-in-images-with-machine-learning-on-android-f929556589fc) will help.